# Wcf Castle Windsor

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I am using the Wcf Facility, (windsor 2.5.2) latest version from github repo as of last week.

how ever it is not working throwing the following error (when the service starts up)

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

here is the setup

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(); 
        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
            .Register(
            Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
            Component.For<Session>().ImplementedBy<Session>().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation(),
            Component.For<IService1>().ImplementedBy<Service1>().AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel()).LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation());
```

removing all the windsor stuff back to a vanilla service it works fine.

the error is thrown in "Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHost" on line 32

```
this.model = model;
```

thanks

bones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seemed to be happening, was on setup Castle would start to create the service, which at that point did not have the base address being passed to it (observation, I could have this a little incorrect)

i found another post where the developer used

```
Component.For<IService1>().ImplementedBy<Service1>().ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel().Hosted()).LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation()
```

it seems to work (I have even taken [a quick video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agOQkijWTus))

I guess the only question i have "is this the correct way of registering a service?" the wiki and demo app show different ways which do not work with the example in the video.