# Wcf Service PerCall WcfFacility

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

how can i get the WcfFacility to make my service Per call, I have tried

`Component.For<IService1>().ImplementedBy<Service1>().AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel()).LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation()`

however when I run the WCF Test client with out the "create new proxy" box ticked it does not run the ctor everytime.

please help

bones

(ps this is not same issue as the other post of mine, that is still an issue too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you specified percall at the service definition:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)] 
class MyService : IMyContract {...}
```

Comment: this does work however I was looking for another way without the default service behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Shiraz pointed out a way which I was aware of however knowning castle does lifeStyle management of PerCall and PerSession, i was hoping for a way which did not include the default attributes.

I recently [changed the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394022/wcf-castle-windsor/5399393#5399393) of code in the question to

```
Component.For<IService1>().ImplementedBy<Service1>().ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel().Hosted()).LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation()
```

which resulted in a PerCall (on my machine). Would be very interested if this was the intended behaviour